# Ipinfo.io Geolocation working in JSfiddle but not Codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple geolocation fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cbtzzLjs/17/

```
<div id="address"></div>

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Awesome " + response.region);
/*     $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4)); */
}, "jsonp");
```

It doesn't work in Codepen.

https://codepen.io/Teeke/pen/EEeReM

I tried prepending https to my codepen url. I loaded JQuery and disabled auto-reload in codepen to not burn through my rate limit.

The codepen console returns:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://static.codepen.io/assets/telefon/bold/af889c53-1ee3-4868-8fdc-2b310d587b50-3-b7a87e0fbd213943fae0c0ef5985635dd43fa9c24876b2725127a13ccaf4ab6a.woff. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://codepen.io’).
```

Is this an internal codepen setting? Can I use a geolocation API under their terms and conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `http://ipinfo.io` to `https://ipinfo.io` in codepen since you are trying to access ip from a secured origin of codepen.

So, your js should be as follows in codepen:

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Awesome " + response.region);
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: I didn't realize I had to change the ipinfo setting to https. I'll accept this answer.Thanks.